# How to get data from S-record file

Tags: microcontroller, programming

Please tell me something about the S-record file format and how we can get data from it.

The first S1 record is comprised as follows:

•   S1 S-record type S1, indicating it is a data record to be loaded at a 2-byte address.

•   13 Hexadecimal 13 (decimal 19), indicating that nineteen character pairs, representing a 2 byte address, 16 bytes of binary data, and a 1 byte checksum, follow.

•   00 00 Four character 2-byte address field; hexidecimal address 0x0000, where the data which follows is to be loaded.

•   28 5F 24 5F 22 12 22 6A 00 04 24 29 00 08 23 7C Sixteen character pairs representing the actual binary data.

•   2A The checksum.

Comment: You have just explained how the data is formatted in it (which is all on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-record) too) - so what exactly is the question? What data are you missing?

Comment: I have no idea what a "S-record" is without some context.

Answer (score 2):

I use http://srecord.sourceforge.net/ for converting various file types. Amongst many other formats, it supports Motorola S-records and IntelHEX.

It can also be used to extract certain fields/bytes from a file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running Windows ARM publish a free utility that converts Motorola S-records to binary:

http://www.keil.com/download/docs/10.asp

If running Linux or you would like to see source code examples the following site may be of assistance:

http://www.s-record.com/