# how we can get original data from S-record format file

Tags: microcontroller, programming

I have a S-Record file how i can get original program from this file 
plz tell me

EXAMPLE

```
Shown below is a typical S-record format file.

    S00600004844521B                              
    S1130000285F245F2212226A000424290008237C2A
    S11300100002000800082629001853812341001813
    S113002041E900084E42234300182342000824A952
    S107003000144ED492
    S5030004F8
    S9030000FC
```

Comment: Please go back and edit [the question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/64979/14004) you posted earlier on this subject, instead of posting a fresh one, thanks.

Comment: This question is different from the other posting. In this one Rahul is wondering how to get the original program back. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get the original program back from the S-Record file. There was a compilation or assembly process used to convert the original program source code into the binary pattern of machine language code that would run on the target hardware. In that translation process the source code is not recoverable from the S-Record output.

There is one step that can be taken though. However to be able to do this step it is essential to know what target hardware environment was. What MCU was used? How was the S-Record data positioned in the MCU's executable program space? Do you understand the MCU's instruction set?

If you know all of the above and some more about the platform that the S-Record data was used in it may be possible to disassemble the binary data back into the assembly language opcodes that comprise the execution flow of the program. This will not be the original program but could provide you an understanding of what the program is attempting to do.

For a small amount of data like you showed it is possible to do this dis-assembly manually by looking at an op-code chart for the specific MCU. Tedious work to say the least. There are some tools that aid in the dis-assembly process for specific MCU instruction sets but since you provided no information about the platform structure you would have to search out those options on your own.

Do note if the program that you are trying to re-discover is part of a larger batch of S-Record data then trying to disassemble the MCU code could very well be illegal. Unless you happen to be either the rightful owner of the program code or an agent of such rightful owner than it is considered theft to be disassembling someones code. If it is your own code and you somehow lost the original program source code then consider this an important lesson in learning how to keep proper and safe backups.